How to deal with former student requests to be co-author?
I am a fairly new assistant professor in a social science discipline and I've started encountering the situation where students I've supervised at the masters or PhD level finish their dissertations and want to publish papers based on their work. Several have contacted me asking whether I would like to be a co-author on the resulting paper. In some cases, I feel uncertain about accepting co-authorship. Here are the reasons I’ve considered for and against it, and I’d appreciate your thoughts on which are the most compelling.
Reasons Against Being a Co-Author:
Ability to take responsibility for the work. I believe all co-authors, especially senior ones, should take responsibility for the paper’s arguments, methods, and conclusions. If the papers I was being offered co-authorship on were in an area that I'm an expert on then I'd have no qualms about taking this responsibility. However, students are offering me authorship on papers that are outside my core areas of expertise. They are either ones in which I was one of several advisors, and advised on a small area of the content, and have little knowledge about other aspects, or ones where I felt comfortable to supervise a students' work, but wouldn't feel comfortable taking ownership of the specific conclusions they came to in the published literature.
Relevance to my own CV. I worry that having a large number of papers on my CV on areas not directly related to my core areas of interest/expertise will dilute my CV, and make it harder for people to understand what my research is about. I'm already publishing a large enough volume of papers to keep up with expectations, and in my country quality of research outputs is valued more highly than volume. As a result, my own research is deliberately concentrated into a small number of papers at fairly high impact journals.
Time and effort. If I put time into reading and commenting on drafts, and helping students through the publication process (e.g. dealing with peer reviewers) then this is time I could spend doing other things.
Reasons to be a co-author
Publications on my CV. Surely, all else equal, more publications is better.
It provides evidence that I am an effective supervisor.
Do I have a responsibility to students to help them publish their work?  Students' work may be evaluated more positively by journal editors if it has my name on it as a coauthor. I can also help students to deal with responding to reviewers and other aspects of the publication process.
According to ICJME guidelines, if I provide substantial feedback on the draft, I would meet the criteria for co-authorship. But I’m still unsure how to balance these considerations.
How do others handle this situation? What factors should I prioritize?

You accept authorship for papers where you had important input and agree with the message (and quality) of the paper. If you had input, but do not agree with message and quality, you can be generous to let the student publish while acknowledging you.

(1) I'm confused how you were supervising students whose topics were so far from your own they would look irrelevant on your CV? (2) Do you work in medicine? ICJME's guidelines are not universal.

@AzorAhai-him- 1) in my department/discipline masters' students have a lot of latitude for choosing their dissertation topic, so students can end up writing dissertations on topics that aren't the direct specialism of the supervisor. In the case of the PhD student, I was assigned as a second supervisor to advise on a specific methodological aspect of the project. 2) No I'm not in medicine - this issue only arose when one of my students submitted to a journal that does use ICJME criteria for determining authorship

and in my country quality of research outputs is valued more highly than volume. Are you sure? I have never heard of an academic system that does such an amazing job of measuring research quality that they do not put significant value on volume as well volume. It's hard to say for sure without knowing more details, but your calculation of the drawbacks of agreeing to be added as a coauthor seems exaggerated to me personally, and your estimation of the benefits sounds too conservative.

Maybe it's because I'm in a different area, but I don't think having a few papers from outside your core areas of interest will dilute the CV. A CV section called "Research interests" or "Research overview" makes it easier to understand what your research is about than an ever-expanding list of paper titles anyway.

First, I guess I'm a bit of an extremist on this, but my advice is to not consider yourself a co-author on a student's paper, even at the doctoral level, unless your relationship with them was collegial/collaborative rather than an advisor role. Let them have sole authorship and list your contributions in an acknowledgment section.
Note, importantly that the ICJME guidelines have four aspects with the word and not or between them. They are all important aspects, not just one.
My view is that those guidelines are the minimum and that the first of them is essential. While I advised my doctoral students on their dissertations and provided help, I was never a co-author on their resulting publications. Nor was my dissertation advisor an author on mine (in math, of course), though he suggested the problem and advised on the results.
I do acknowledge that in some fields, such as lab sciences requiring massive funding, advisors, PIs actually, are authors quite naturally because without their support the work could not be undertaken in the first place. I find that a bit distasteful, but also natural. Likewise something like field-work in a field like anthropology might be similar, due to the required funding and the cooperative nature of such investigations.
The key for me in authorship is who has provided the key intellectual content of the paper. There can be several contributors to that, hence several authors, but "hard work" and "review" isn't enough for me. Who has provided the ideas expressed in the paper?
An alternate reason, important to me, is that sole authorship for a beginner can be a boost and I'd rather not have people question their work, suggesting it was "really" mine.
I don't work in social science, so math and CS may be giving me a bias here, I recognize. But generosity is a virtue.
But yes, help them get published in any way you can. There are many other ways than your possible name recognition. That focuses it on you, when, IMO, it should be on them and on the work itself.
